# Error while access to packet in Scapy Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
pkt = PcapReader('test.pcap').read_all()[55]
```

My problem is that the last line throw an exception :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 527 in __repr__ val = f.i2repr(self,fval)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1335 in i2repr val = super(_StrField, self).i2repr(pkt, x)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 226 i2repr return repr(self.i2h(pkt, x))
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549 in __repr__ repr(self.payload)
[Previous line repeated 321 more times]
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 519, in __repr__ ct = conf.color_them
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\config.py", line 887, in __getattribute__ return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
File "c:\pthon3\lib\site-packages\scapy\config.py", line 101, in __get__ if not hasattr(obj, self.intname):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Scapy verion = 2.4.5

Why is that ?

Comment: please provide fully working code and full stack trace so it can be clearly seen at which line the exception pops

Comment: @rok I have edit my post

Comment: Why are you adding the `[55]` part while reading? Are you sure that TCP exists in the read part? You can probably `print` and validate?

Comment: @DebashisDeb I hace edit my post , I cann't access to packet this at all